# RN-42 + Android Receive Message Issues

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am building an Android application to communicate with my NR-42 bluetooth device. I am able to connect to the bluetooth and send data to the device which is a PIC18F but I am not able to receive bluetooth data from my device to my android phone.

I am following this example http://solderer.tv/data-transfer-between-android-and-arduino-via-bluetooth/comment-page-1/

When I use tera-term it shows me that the bluetooth module is doing what it is suppose to do, but I can't get the data in my textViews. I am trying to send float data. I am new to android but the issue is happening here I assume.

```
  h = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
            case RECIEVE_MESSAGE:                                                   // if receive massage
                byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                String strIncom = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);                 // create string from bytes array
                sb.append(strIncom);                                                // append string
                int endOfLineIndex = sb.indexOf("\r\n");                            // determine the end-of-line
                if (endOfLineIndex > 0) {                                            // if end-of-line,
                    String sbprint = sb.substring(0, endOfLineIndex);               // extract string
                    sb.delete(0, sb.length());                                      // and clear
                    txtArduino.setText("Data from Arduino: " + sbprint);            // update TextView
                    btnOff.setEnabled(true);
                    btnOn.setEnabled(true);
                }
                //Log.d(TAG, "...String:"+ sb.toString() +  "Byte:" + msg.arg1 + "...");
                break;
            }
        };
    };
```

"
    The input stream is being read here."

```
    public void run() {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[256];  // buffer store for the stream
        int bytes; // bytes returned from read()

        // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
        while (true) {
            try {
                // Read from the InputStream
                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);        // Get number of bytes and message in "buffer"
                h.obtainMessage(RECIEVE_MESSAGE, bytes, -1, buffer).sendToTarget();     // Send to message queue Handler
                Log.d(TAG, "sent handler");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Has anyone come across this issue or can help me out?

Thanks

Comment: Is handleMessage getting called with any data?

Comment: If I am understanding your comment correctly. handleMessage() is called within the onCreate so doesn't it keep listening for the message thread data?

Comment: I was able to get something to print. I am using sb.toString(); in my textView message handler instead of sbprint. not sure why sbprint won't work accordingly but at least I am getting my data now.